# How to verfiy presence of an <a> tag with a class in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

Just started using Selenium IDE and having trouble verifying the presence of an <a> tag with a specific css class. I can select the <a> tag with "VerifyElementPresent | link=mylink" but how do include the check for the class?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do this using an xPath selector, once I discovered both Firefox and Chrome have a way to get the xPath of an element.